# Scrape data in local storage to get specific information from it such as (key, value and extra)

Tags: javascript, local-storage, scrape

I don't know how to make this code give me the key, value and extra information in local-storage of a specific website in JS. I am beginner in JS and I been stuck in this phase for so long. I have tried some codes with changing them but always gave me error.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('https://www.google.com/')

  const returnedCookie = await page.cookies();  
  console.log(returnedCookie)

  await page.waitForTimeout( 10000 );
  const localStorageData = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let json = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
      const key = localStorage.key(i);
      json[key] = localStorage.getItem(key);
    }
    return json;
  });

  console.log(localStorageData)

  await browser.close()
})()

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
const page = await browser.newPage()
await page.goto('https://www.com/')

const returnedCookie = await page.cookies();  
console.log(returnedCookie)

await page.waitForTimeout( 10000 );
const localStorageData = await page.evaluate(() => {
let json = {};
for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
  const key = localStorage.key(i);
  json[key] = localStorage.getItem(key);
}
return json;
});

console.log(localStorageData)

await browser.close()
})()
```

Comment: You can't for obvious security reasons. Storage is sandboxed to a specific domain. You can't access it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Eval in Js, with js intructions that would interact with localStorage, in a normal web page, u can even develop a micro page, just to find out those instructions

Once u are in pupeeter, you must inject those instructions and sentences, to get info from the localStoreg in the automated browser

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).